# Querying SQL database via DBI::dbGetQuery in RStudio takes 10times longer than in RGui

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rstudio, r-dbi

Queering a SQL database using the following:

```r
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "NAME_OF_SQL_SERVER", database = "NAME_OF_DB")
system.time(x <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "Exemplary_Data_ByDateRange @dtFrom  = '2016/01/01' , @dtTo  = '2019/03/01'"))
```

takes me in RGui around 0.7 seconds:

> user  system elapsed 
>   0.59    0.08    0.67

but in RStudio 8.5 seconds:

> user  system elapsed 
>   8.51    0.03    8.55

and I have no idea why that is the case / how to fix it.
I have the following setup:

> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          6.0
>   year           2019
>   month          04
>   day            26
>   svn rev        76424
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
>   nickname       Planting of a Tree

I've tried the following:

- options(connectionObserver = NULL)
- Reinstalling drivers odbc 13/17
- Wiping out and reinstalling RStudio
- Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2017